# C++ Data structures allocator issues

Tags: c++, data-structures, allocator

I'm having trouble implementing my Graph in C++.

For now, I've just implemented Vertex and Edges, here are the classes:

Vertex.h

```
#ifndef VERTEX_H_
#define VERTEX_H_
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace MarcoGraphs {

enum class Colors {black, red};

class Vertex {
private:
    std::string id;
    int soglia, degree;
    double peso;
    Colors visited;
public:
    Vertex(std::string id);
    Vertex(const Vertex& param);
    Vertex& operator=(const Vertex& param);
    Vertex(Vertex&& param);
    Vertex& operator=(Vertex&& param);
    ~Vertex();
    bool operator!=(const Vertex& param);
    bool operator==(const Vertex& param);
    bool operator<(const Vertex& param);
    std::string getId();
    void setDegree(int degree);
    int getDegree();
    void incrementDegree();
    void setSoglia(int soglia);
    int getSoglia();
    void setVisited(Colors mycolors);
    Colors getVisited();
    void setPeso(double peso);
    double getPeso();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Vertex& a);
};

} /* namespace MarcoGraphs */

#endif /* VERTEX_H_ */
```

Vertex.cpp

```
#include "Vertex.h"

namespace MarcoGraphs {

Vertex::Vertex(std::string Id):
    id(Id), soglia(0), degree(0), peso(0), visited(Colors::black){
}

Vertex::~Vertex() {
}

Vertex::Vertex(const Vertex& param):
    id(param.id), soglia(param.soglia), degree(param.degree), peso(param.degree), visited(param.visited){
}

Vertex& Vertex::operator=(const Vertex& param){
    id = param.id;
    soglia = param.soglia;
    degree = param.degree;
    peso = param.peso;
    visited = param.visited;
    return *this;
}

Vertex::Vertex(Vertex&& param):
        id(param.id), soglia(param.soglia), degree(param.degree), peso(param.degree), visited(param.visited){
    param.id.clear();
}

Vertex& Vertex::operator=(Vertex&& param){
    id = param.id;
    param.id.clear();
    soglia = param.soglia;
    degree = param.degree;
    peso = param.peso;
    visited = param.visited;
    return *this;
}

bool Vertex::operator!=(const Vertex& param){
    return !(this->id==param.id);
}

bool Vertex::operator==(const Vertex& param){
    return this->id==param.id;
}

bool Vertex::operator<(const Vertex& param){
    return this->id<param.id;
}

std::string Vertex::getId(){
    return id;
}

void Vertex::setDegree(int degree){
    this->degree = degree;
}

int Vertex::getDegree(){
    return degree;
}

void Vertex::incrementDegree(){
    degree +=1;
}

void Vertex::setSoglia(int soglia){
    this->soglia = soglia;
}

int Vertex::getSoglia(){
    return soglia;
}

void Vertex::setVisited(Colors mycolor){
    this->visited = mycolor;
}

Colors Vertex::getVisited(){
    return visited;
}

void Vertex::setPeso(double peso){
    this->peso = peso;
}

double Vertex::getPeso(){
    return peso;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Vertex& a){
    out << a.id << " " << a.peso << " " << a.soglia << "\n";
    return out;
}

} /* namespace MarcoGraphs */
```

Edge.h

```
#ifndef EDGE_H_
#define EDGE_H_
#include <iostream>
#include "Vertex.h"

namespace MarcoGraphs {

class Edge {
private:
    Vertex* v1;
    Vertex* v2;
public:
    Edge(Vertex v1, Vertex v2);
    Edge(const Edge& param);
    Edge& operator=(const Edge& param);
    Edge(Edge&& param);
    Edge& operator=(Edge&& param);
    ~Edge();

    bool operator!=(const Edge& param);
    bool operator==(const Edge& param);
    bool operator<(const Edge& param);
    Vertex* getV1();
    Vertex* getV2();

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Edge& a);
};

} /* namespace MarcoGraphs */

#endif /* EDGE_H_ */
```

Edge.cpp

```
#include "Edge.h"

namespace MarcoGraphs {

Edge::Edge(Vertex v1, Vertex v2):
    v1(&v1), v2(&v2){
}

Edge::~Edge() {
}

Edge::Edge(const Edge& param):
    v1(param.v1), v2(param.v2){
}

Edge& Edge::operator=(const Edge& param){
    v1 = param.v1;
    v2 = param.v2;
    return *this;
}

Edge::Edge(Edge&& param):
    v1(param.v1), v2(param.v2){
    param.v1 = nullptr;
    param.v2 = nullptr;
}

Edge& Edge::operator=(Edge&& param){
    v1 = param.v1;
    v2 = param.v2;
    param.v1 = nullptr;
    param.v2 = nullptr;
    return *this;
}

bool Edge::operator!=(const Edge& param){
    return !(*v1 == *(param.v1) && *v2 == *(param.v2));
}


bool Edge::operator==(const Edge& param){
    return (*v1 == *(param.v1) && *v2 == *(param.v2));
}

bool Edge::operator<(const Edge& param){
    if(*v1 != *(param.v1))
        return *v1 < *(param.v1);
    return *v2 < *(param.v2);
}

Vertex* Edge::getV1(){
    return v1;
}


Vertex* Edge::getV2(){
    return v2;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Edge& a){
    out << a.v1->getId() << "," << a.v2->getId();
    return out;
}

} /* namespace MarcoGraphs */
```

I tried to test these classes with this small example:

main.cpp

```
#include "Vertex.h"
#include "Edge.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    MarcoGraphs::Vertex v1("Marco");
    MarcoGraphs::Vertex v2("Stefano");
    MarcoGraphs::Vertex v3("Giovanni");


    std::vector<MarcoGraphs::Vertex> v(10);
    v.push_back(v1);
    v.push_back(v2);
    v.push_back(v3);
    return 0;
}
```

But g++ gives me the following errors:

```
15:15:20 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Thesis ****
make all 
Building file: ../Main.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"Main.d" -MT"Main.d" -o "Main.o" "../Main.cpp"
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_tempbuf.h:60:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_algo.h:62,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9.0/algorithm:62,
                 from ../Main.cpp:12:
/usr/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = MarcoGraphs::Vertex; _Args = {}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:515:43:   required from ‘static void std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<_TrivialValueType>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = MarcoGraphs::Vertex*; _Size = unsigned int; bool _TrivialValueType = false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:570:33:   required from ‘void std::__uninitialized_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = MarcoGraphs::Vertex*; _Size = unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:631:50:   required from ‘void std::__uninitialized_default_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _ForwardIterator = MarcoGraphs::Vertex*; _Size = unsigned int; _Tp = MarcoGraphs::Vertex]’
/usr/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1311:28:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_initialize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = MarcoGraphs::Vertex; _Alloc = std::allocator<MarcoGraphs::Vertex>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_vector.h:279:34:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = MarcoGraphs::Vertex; _Alloc = std::allocator<MarcoGraphs::Vertex>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<MarcoGraphs::Vertex>]’
../Main.cpp:21:39:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘MarcoGraphs::Vertex::Vertex()’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9.0/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../Main.cpp:8:0:
../Vertex.h:27:2: note: MarcoGraphs::Vertex::Vertex(MarcoGraphs::Vertex&&)
  Vertex(Vertex&& param);
  ^
../Vertex.h:27:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../Vertex.h:25:2: note: MarcoGraphs::Vertex::Vertex(const MarcoGraphs::Vertex&)
  Vertex(const Vertex& param);
  ^
../Vertex.h:25:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../Vertex.h:24:2: note: MarcoGraphs::Vertex::Vertex(std::string)
  Vertex(std::string id);
  ^
../Vertex.h:24:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
subdir.mk:24: recipe for target 'Main.o' failed
make: *** [Main.o] Error 1
```

Can you help me?Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zsolt's answer is correct, but perhaps doesn't fully answer your question.  So I'll try to expand on it.

In C++, the "default constructor" is a constructor that is called without arguments.  In the case of Vertex, Vertex().

When you create a class and do not define any constructors, C++ creates a default constructor for you, which may be why you have not yet encountered this problem.  In the case of Vertex, you have created some constructors, so the compiler believes you have explicitly left out a default constructor.  This is often desirable since often no meaningful default exists.

When you call the line:

```
std::vector<MarcoGraphs::Vertex> v(10);
```

You are telling the compiler you want to construct a vector of 10 Vertexes.  Since you have not provided an allocator as a template argument, it uses the default allocator, which calls the default constructor, which does not exist.  This is what the errors you are seeing are telling you (read them again now, and you should be able to understand their output).

In your main loop you are using push_back to add the Vertexes to your vector, so in fact there is no need to contruct 10 default Vertexes.  You have several options:

1. Delete the "(10)" from your definition of v, and let the compiler allocate memory for you (preferred in this case).
2. Create a meaninful default constructor (probably wrong in this case).
3. Follow Zsolt's advice and reserve the memory.

Reserving the memory is really an optimization, which is useful when you know how many objects a vector will store, and don't want to reallocate memory on the fly with the push_back command.  For your concrete program I would consider this a premature optimization, and would just delete the "(10)".

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<MarcoGraphs::Vertex> v(10);` This creates a vector with 10 elements, but for that it needs a default constructor, which you don't have.

You can either use `reserve` to have a big enough vector, or pass in a `Vertex` to the constructor of the vector.

Here, have some reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector